# How to call javascript inside flex 3?

Tags: javascript, flex3

```
function func(param)
{
 ...
}
```

How to call an external javascript function `func` with `param` as parameter inside flex 3?

Answer (score 0):

Use "ExternalInterface.call" method or use Flex-Ajax bridge to communicate with JavaScript. More info can be found here:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ajaxbridge_1.html